# How to fix an error with the weather command

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const weather = require('weather-js');
 
module.exports = {
    name: 'weather',
    description: 'weather',
    execute(message, args){
        const { prefix, token } = require ('../config.json');

        if(!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send("Please give the weather location")
        }
    
    weather.find({search: args.join(" "), degreeType: 'C'}, function(err, result) {
        try {
 
let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`weather - ${result[0].location.name}`)
.setColor("#fffff1")
.setDescription("Temperature units can may be differ some time")
.addField("Temperature", `${result[0].current.temperature} Celcius`, true)
.addField("Sky Text", result[0].current.skytext, true)
.addField("Humidity", result[0].current.humidity, true)
.addField("Wind Speed", result[0].current.windspeed, true)//What about image
.addField("Observation Time", result[0].current.observationtime, true)
.addField("Wind Display", result[0].current.winddisplay, true)
.setThumbnail(result[0].current.imageUrl);
   message.channel.send(embed)
} catch(err) {
  return message.channel.send("Unable To Get the data of Given location")
}
});   
}
}
```

When I use the command **!weather**, works normally showing `Provides the location of the climate`

But if I place the city, for example **!weather Los Angeles**, it always gives me the error `Unable To Get the data of Given location`, any city I place always appears like this.

Comment: Are you able to obtain the raw JS response from whatever Weather API is being called?

Comment: It would be helpful to have the actual error message it outputs, you catch the error, but never print it anywhere, so there's no way of knowing what it actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say... did you realize your discord identifier is wrong?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

then

```
...
let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
...
```

Try Changing it to:

```
...
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
...
```